# Add copy to pdf after opening it in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to add the text COPY to an invoice that i created with PHP FPDF. but i want it only to the saved file(not to the opened file). Anyone a idea how 2 do this?

I have tried to do this

```
function AddCopy(){
   $pdf->Write(12, "COPY");
   $filename="../FPDF/PDF/Facturen/".$bestelnummer.".pdf";
   $pdf->Output($filename,'F','s');
} $pdf->Output();
  AddCopy();
```

also tried i this:

```
$pdf->Output();
$filename="../FPDF/PDF/Facturen/".$bestelnummer.".pdf";
$pdf->Write(12, "COPY");
$pdf->Output($filename,'F','s');
```

i want to get COPY on the saved file

Comment: You'll need 2 files... read docu of Output(): `The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I will try this tomorrow. hope this works.